# Variables as www.example.com/var1/var2/

Tags: php, javascript

I want to make something like:

```
www.example.com/var1/var2/
```

where I can take the value of the variables, but it also need to be compatible with `GET` like:

```
www.example.com/var1/var2/?feat=1234
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php. This link would help

Comment: The `.htaccess` route in the link above will require the flag `[QSA]` for your example link to work

Comment: @Bora Looks like the OP wants only partial re write `?this=1&andthis=2&butnotthis=3` to `/1/2?butnotthis=3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?php`
`$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`
`$url_splitter = explode('/', $url);`
`echo '<pre>';`
`print_r($url_splitter);`
`?>`

Now you can access the variables by taking `$url_splitter[0]`, `$url_splitter[1]`,`....`

Comment: But this require me to have folders called var1 and var2...

Answer (score -2):

Check out [symfony](http://symfony.com/) or [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

The documentation will explain how to do a mod rewrite to get the url you want.

A partial re write can be done in this way (have not tested)

http://forums.devshed.com/apache-development-15/partial-mod-rewrite-454669.html

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

That should turn a url like `/foo/bar/?var3=baz` into `/index.php?var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=baz` I am not sure it'll work though because I don't know how the regexp in the mod rewrite works.

Comment: A whole framework for URL rewriting??

Comment: @SmokeyPHP `The documentation will explain how to do a mod rewrite to get the url you want.` And yes, I might as well mention the framework as it makes for some interesting reading.